# Islam related question

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

A.O.A dear friends n fellows... I have a question... I have been in a relationship wid a lady... She was my collegue n we happened to develop likeness for each other... N confessed to each other about our feelings n we were in contct with each other over phone via sms n sometimes only a few times over call that i can count dat on fingers... I have taked to my parents, they agreed bt she hasnt told at her side to anyone rite now... We have never talked abt sex or intimacy n always tried to keep our discussion clean.. Now she wants to stop even dat.. As she says dat its not rite, which doesnt seem to me as a good option as we both are mature n has set some limits n we are not voilating then at all.. We both have clear consience abt dat... Bt she says its not allowed in Islam dat we shud ever talk to each other...n iam not fully agreed with this...

Plz tell me is there any condition in Islam in which we cud have this sort of relationship going without being sinful??? And uptil now we both are totally sure that we want to marry each other...

Comment: First it would be easier ro read your post if you wrote in clean English. If you told your parents about her what hinsers you to ask for her hand in marriage as a fiance you coyld at least meet her if she is in company of a mahram or an other woman or maybe in a public place.

Comment: She doesnt want to meet because at the moment she havent told anybody n according to her its not the rite time to disclose this to her family.

Comment: Well this still doesn't sound like a satisfactory reason to me. You could ask her to meet in public in company of a female friend or a mahram of hers or your sister... But if she wants to marry you she should tell her parents and you may go ask for her hand and use the time of engagement to get to know eachother better.

Answer (score 1):

Until you are married to her, she is a non-mahram and you shouldn't be with her in seclusion.

> No person (man) should be alone with a woman except when there is a
>   Mahram with her.[ [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/478) and [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/215) ]
>
> A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan
>   (Satan). [ [Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/urn/674690) ]

You should also consider that even though you might think yourself capable of restraint, but in the end people are weak-willed and eventually fall to temptations ... you are risking the sin of *Zina*.